# Application of design pattern on a concrete task

Tags: design-patterns, predict, recursive-datastructures

input example:

```
<pdf>
    <page 1><addressbox><value>adress 1</value></addressbox></page>
    <page 2><addressbox><value>adress 2</value></addressbox></page>
    <page 3><addressbox><value>adress 2</value></addressbox></page>
    <page 4><addressbox><value>adress 2</value></addressbox></page>
    <page 5><addressbox><value>adress 3</value></addressbox></page>
    <page 6><addressbox><value></value></addressbox></page>
    <page 7><addressbox><value>adress 3</value></addressbox></page>
    <page 8><addressbox><value>adress 4</value></addressbox></page>
    <page 9><addressbox><value>i am not a adress</value></addressbox></page>    
    <page 10>
        <addressbox>
            <value>adress 6</value>
            <collect>true</collect>
        </addressbox>
    </page>
    <page 11><addressbox><value>address 7</value></addressbox></page>
    <page 12><addressbox><value>address 2</value></addressbox></page>
</pdf>
</code>
```

**goal:** 
collect pages to logical units

**definition:**
If the value of the string starts with "address" then it's a valid address otherwise not.

**rules:**

- first page starts a logical unit
- the following pages belong to the previous logical unit if it has the same value or is a empty value or collect=true

the results should look like this:

```
<unit>
    <unit 1>page1</unit>
    <unit 2>page2, page3, page4</unit>
    <unit 3>page5, page6, page7</unit>
    <unit 4>page8</unit>
    <unit 5>page9</unit>
    <unit 6>page10, page11</unit>
    <unit 7>page12</unit>

</unit>
```

I would like to solve the problem with design pattern, since the rules might change slightly.
Got the Pattern Visitor, Decorator, Composite and Chain of responsibility watched and not really found something.

Which pattern would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the State Design Pattern. I will explain briefly and then attach a whiteboard diagram pic which is self-explanatory -

1. The system has 2 states -

   1. New Unit State - When it gets a page which satisfies the new unit criteria, like the first page will always - application enters the new state.
   2. Same unit state - When it gets the same unit it enters this state
2. You need to create States' subclasses for these two states in your State Pattern implementation.
3. The unit count which you need for the output's unit numbers will be maintained in the Context of the state pattern.

[image]

(To get full details of how to implement state pattern you can refer my blog article on the same at-http://www.javabrahman.com/design-patterns/state-design-pattern-in-java/)